# First UITableViewCell UIButton in search remains the same

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a table that loads 3 cells. The first cell's label text is "Don" and the last 2 cells' label texts are "Test".

I've noticed when I search for “Don” first, the UIButton tag is 100 (correct tag #). Then next I'll search "Test" and the first cell's UIButton tag is 100 (should be 101) and the second cell's UIButton tag is 102 (correct).

When I rerun the application and search for "Test" first, the first cell's UIButton tag is 101 (correct) and the second cell's UIButton tag is 102 (correct). But when I search for "Don" afterwards, the cell's UIButton tag is 101 (should be 100).

I'm not sure if it's overlapping only on the first cell or what but I am providing my cell code below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// register cell identifier from custom cell NIB
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FriendCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Avatar settings
UIImageView *imvAvatar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 3, 45, 45)];
[imvAvatar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnAvatar2.png"]];
imvAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = imvAvatar.frame.size.height/2;
imvAvatar.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
//imvAvatar.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:59/255 green:59/255 blue:121/255 alpha:1].CGColor;
//imvAvatar.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

// Befriend Button settings
UIButton *btnBefriend = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(281, 14, 36, 22)];
[btnBefriend addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBefriendPressed:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Collect friend info

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    friend = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
} else {
    friend = [arrFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
}

NSString *user_id = (NSString *)[friend objectAtIndex:0];    // user id
NSString *username = (NSString *)[friend objectAtIndex:1];   // username
NSString *fName = (NSString *)[friend objectAtIndex:2];      // first name
NSString *lName = (NSString *)[friend objectAtIndex:3];      // last name
NSString *full_name = (NSString *)[friend objectAtIndex:4];  // full name
UIImage *picture = (UIImage *)[friend objectAtIndex:5];      // picture (img)
NSString *type = (NSString *)[friend objectAtIndex:6];       // type
NSString *arrIndex = (NSString *)[friend objectAtIndex:7];   // arrFriends index

// configure cell
if (!cell) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // set width depending on device orientation
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);

    // Name settings
    UILabel *lblName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(60, 3, 215, 45))];
    [lblName setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];

    // Update name, status, picture, befriend button
    lblName.text = full_name;                           // full name
    imvAvatar.image = picture;                          // picture (img)
    if ([type isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [btnBefriend setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnBefriend.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else {
        [btnBefriend setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnBefriended.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    // Cell subviews
    imvAvatar.tag = 1;
    lblName.tag = 2;
    btnBefriend.tag = [arrIndex intValue]+100;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imvAvatar];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblName];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btnBefriend];
    cell.clipsToBounds = YES;

}
else {
    // Make sure images, buttons and texts don't overlap

    // avatar
    UIImageView *imvAvatar = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    imvAvatar.image = picture;
    // name
    UILabel *lblName = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    lblName.text = full_name;
    // befriendbutton
    UIButton *btnBefriend = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:[arrIndex intValue]+100];
    if ([type isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [btnBefriend setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnBefriend.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else {
        [btnBefriend setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnBefriended.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

return cell;
}
```

I assumed the problem would be on the lines:

```
friend = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
and/or
UIButton *btnBefriend = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:[arrIndex intValue]+100];
```

but the corect imageview and label texts appear, so I am not entirely sure what's causing this problem.

Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This probably has to due with your call to `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. Read the documentation about that  method.

Comment: By why do the second cells have the correct tags and not the first result?

Comment: I edited my answer with more information.

Comment: That didn't fix my problem. Would a custom cell solve this problem or would I still have the tag value issues?

Answer (score 0):

From the Apple documentation

[UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

`-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`

> **...**
>
> If an existing cell was available for reuse, this method calls the
>   cell’s **prepareForReuse** method instead.

[UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

`-prepareForReuse`

> **...**
>
> The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: **should
>   always reset all content when reusing a cell.**
>
> **...**

**Edit - more info**
I do not see you explicitly setting the tag value in your code. Read this from the Apple documentation. Perhaps this is why the values are incorrect also.

> UIView.tag
>
> The default value is 0. You can set the value of this tag and use that value to identify the view >later.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie to objective c. What changes do I need to make to my code?

Comment: Which view am I not setting that you are referring to? I am setting the tags for: imvAvatar.tag = 1; lblName.tag = 2; and btnBefriend.tag = [arrIndex intValue]+100;

Comment: I didn't see that line in your code. Move `btnBefriend.tag = [arrIndex intValue]+100;` above the `if` statement, so that it is reconfigured each time you create the cell instead of the cell being reused and the value not being set.

Comment: Didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Would a custom cell solve this problem or would I still have the tag value issues?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom UITableViewCell with avatr image and Buttons and all other necessary elements which are required and then reuse this custom cell. If u are adding elements to cell in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` then, only the cell will be reused not the ui elements like `imvAvatar` , `btnBefriend` which you are adding to the cell, these elements will be initialised . This can cause memory issues as well

Comment: I've considered this option. Will this change my tag value issue in the Search Results? Or is this change only for memory issues?

Comment: From the search result cell objects you can get UI elements separately, You dont need to tag elements

Comment: Each cell is like a Facebook friend or Instagram follower. I am tagging the cells' buttons to know which user is being selected for an actionsheet that appears when the button is clicked (actionsheet options vary per user). Is there an alternate way of doing this? This is my only reason for tagging the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can try to implement in following way. Since the Cell is reuse we need to maintain the properties of cell if needed. you can refer the following code:

This is called :" Adding subviews to a cell’s content view"

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
        UILabel *firstNameLbl, *lastNameLbl ,*userNameLbl ;

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            firstNameLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(79, 1, 242, 33)];
            firstNameLbl.tag = 500;

            lastNameLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(79, 30, 241, 20)];
            lastNameLbl.tag = 501;

            userNameLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(79, 50, 242, 18)];
            musicNarratedByLbl.tag = 502;


            [cell.contentView addSubview: firstNameLbl];
            [cell.contentView addSubview: lastNameLbl];
            [cell.contentView addSubview: userNameLbl];


        }else{
            firstNameLbl = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:500];
            lastNameLbl = (UILabel* )[cell.contentView viewWithTag:501];
            userNameLbl = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:502];

        }
 // Here is the code for checking the searchresult controller or normal tableview and apply the data to the lable like as follow;  

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)            {
       //grab and apply content to each element of Search Results TableView from defined Searche array to each of the lables      

 }
else
{
//grab and apply content to each element of Table view from defined array to each of the lables
}

return cell;  
}
```

For more Detail you can refer Apple referance code snippet.
In that link refer : **Listing 5-7  Adding subviews to a cell’s content view**

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Comment: I've added this code in the if (searrchResultsTableView) statements: btnBefriend.tag = [arrIndex intValue]+100; and the button tag for the first cell remains the same.

Comment: you need to check this condition during cell reuse only.The way it is written in my code snippit you just need to apply tag to each Ui object ref. and in the end check for type of tableview and assign the value strings to it. i think it will work for you .Please give it a try.

Comment: In my code, I am setting the imageview tag to 1, the label tag to 2 and the button tag to an index number in an array. the first cell in the search results displays the correct image and label text but NOT the correct button even if I change the button tag in the if statement.